# Laravel, personalizar errores de validación

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-6, laravel-7

estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Laravel y en el controlador tengo un método que valida los datos recibidos de un formulario y quiero personalizar los mensajes de validación.

El primer mensaje "age.numeric" se ejecuta correctamente si envío un parámetro "nulo", pero si envío un valor "9" deberia recibir **La edad debe estar entre :min y :max** , pero recibo este mensaje
**El campo age debe ser al menos 10.**

```
    $messages = [
        'age.numeric' => 'La edad debe ser un número',
        'age.between' => 'La edad debe estar entre :min y :max'
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($input, [
        'activity' => 'numeric',
        'age' => 'numeric|min:10|max:120',
    ], $messages);



    if($validator->fails()){
        return $this->jsonValidatorFailedResponse($validator->errors());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes una validación por separado "min" y "max", por eso obtienes mensajes de validación por separado. Lo que debes hacer es usar `between` haciendo hincapié de que es un `integer`:

```
$validator = Validator::make($input, [
    'activity' => 'numeric',
    'age' => 'integer|between:10,120',
], $messages);
```

Comment: gracias, ya he visto el error. 1000 gracias por la respuesta